Should I thank to the editor (mentioning name) and anonymous referees in reply to an acceptance email by chief editor?
I have received an acceptance email from chief editor of a journal. The editor was in cc of the email. They asked for final version as well.
Now I want to reply to that email. But I am not sure how to reply to this acceptance email. Especially, I want advice how to thank the editor for the communication process and the anonymous referee for valuable comments for revision.
I am thinking of something like the following:

Thank you for the acceptance of our article in [journal name]. I will
submit the final version (according to the journal instruction) within
the given time. I would like to thank to Professor [associate Editor name] for
helping in the communication process. I would like to thank the anonymous
referees for their valuable suggestions.

Is this alright? Should I take the name of the editor? or just say "I thank to the editorial board?"
Obviously, associate editor will also receive an reply as he is in cc.
I appreciate for your advice.

This type of contact is simply unnecessary.  There may not even be a mechanism to send the message along to the referees.
If you'd like to credit the referees, the acknowledgement line in the manuscript is a fine place for it.

Ok thank you for your valuable advice. So in the reply email, I just say "thank you for the acceptance email. I will submit the final version in the given period of time".

You don't need a reply email, at all.  There is very little reason to send one.  If you are unable to follow instructions in your acceptance letter, that's a different story.

I know this goes against any advice you've ever heard to "always be gracious and say thank you", but unless the editor has done something very special on your behalf, the main impact of a letter like that is just to give a busy enough person more tedious tasks to deal with.

Good answer. To the OP This is an impersonal email from the editor doing their job. They do not expect gratitude or any further pleasantries. As was mentioned, you would simply be adding another email to delete in their inbox and coming across as "inexperienced" or unfamiliar with the culture of publishing. Simply do the task you were asked for with the final version and submit that as necessary. That is all.
